# Laravel add constraint `1` foreign key when calling foreignIdFor()

Tags: laravel, migration, mysql-8.0, laravel-10

I'm trying to add a foreign key constraint with Laravel's latest migration syntax.

In this case, I have an `Order` model that I am trying to connect to a `Customer` model.

```
Schema::create('customers', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('email');
    $table->string('first_name');
    $table->string('last_name');
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class)->constrained()->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

I would expect this SQL to be executed:

```
alter table `orders` add constraint `customer_id` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`id`)
```

However, Laravel is executing this query:

```
alter table `orders` add constraint `1` foreign key (`customer_id`) references `customers` (`id`)
```

I've looked in the docs on laravel.com and the functionality of the code for the referenced methods and the example I gave of what I expect seems to be in line with how I'd expect the code to behave.

The following syntax does work:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('customer_id')->index();
$table->foreign('customer_id')->references('id')->on('customers');
```

Why am I getting a `1` instead of `customer_id`?

Comment: Does `Customer` have an int autoincrement id or is it a string UUID? What do you have defined in the `Customer` model?

Comment: Auto-increment ID. Updated the original post.

Comment: Figured out the issue but I don't know why this would be happening. If I remove `->index()` from the end of the statement then naming the foreign key works as expected. It seems that `->index()` must come before `->constrained()`.

Comment: I would create an issue on [github](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues) so they can see if it is a true bug or they need to update/make the docs more clear about this behavior, that will help Laravel a lot

Comment: Probably the best thing to do. This feels like a bug.

Comment: Have you modified the `protected $primaryKey` in your Customer class?

Comment: Nope. For the record, this was affecting all of my migrations with foreign keys with indexes.

Answer (score -1):

The `1` in the foreign key constraint name is actually the default behavior of Laravel's `foreignIdFor()` method. It automatically generates a name for the foreign key constraint by concatenating the table name and the column name with an underscore. In this case, since the table is `orders` and the column is `customer_id`, it generates `orders_1` as the constraint name.

To change this behavior and use your own custom constraint name, you can pass it as a parameter to the `constrained()` method:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->foreignIdFor(Customer::class)->constrained('customers_id_foreign')->index();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This will create a foreign key constraint named `customers_id_foreign` instead of the default `orders_1`.

Comment: That doesn't fit the method definition in the `Blueprint` code. If you drill down into the code, you can see it is defined as `constrained($table = null, $column = 'id')` which means the table name and the id cols can be passed, but they shouldn't be needed due to the method functionality being designed to derive those values automatically to construct the foreign key name.